# Postgresql count query

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, subquery, having-clause

I have table with this structure

```
create table job_tags (
    job_id varchar not null,
    tag varchar(50) not null,

    foreign key (job_id) references jobs(id) on delete cascade,
    unique (job_id, tag)
);
```

I would like to perform a single sql query to get tags related to a specific job and its occurrence among ALL jobs.
Right now I have such query which apparently does not work
`SELECT tag, count(tag) as tagcount FROM job_tags WHERE job_id=$1 GROUP BY tagcount ORDER BY tagcount DESC`. It may return only one as tagcount. If anyone knows how to build this query properly I would be very happy! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend `group by`, and filtering with a `having` clause. Postgres' boolean aggregation functions come handy for this:

```
select tag, count(*) as cnt_jobs
from job_tags
group by tag
having bool_or(job_id = $1)
order by cnt_jobs desc
```

Comment: @bredart . . . I think this is the better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sub-query` as follows:

```
SELECT t.tag, count(*) as tagcount FROM job_tags t
WHERE t.tag in (select tt.tag from job_tags tt where tt.job_id=$1)
GROUP BY t.tag
ORDER BY tagcount DESC;
```

Comment: does not work :( ERROR: aggregate functions are not allowed in GROUP BY 
When I remove  GROUP BY  it says that GROUP BY must be in a query

Comment: See the updated answer. In groupby it should be tag. Did that change

Comment: great! it works, thank you very much but need to replace ORDER BY t.tagcount DESC to ORDER BY tagcount DESC;